# passing file attachments in SOAP using suds

Tags: python, soap, suds

We are working on a project where the python client makes RPC call on a Java method

`String uploadFile(String name, String Id)`

Now, this client code has to send an attachment!

```
def sendFile(self, Id, filePath):
    uploadFileMethod = getattr(self.client.service, "uploadFile")
    attachment_id = Id
    attachment_content = (filePath, attachment_id)
    with_soap_attachment(uploadFileMethod, attachment_content)
```

Since, suds does not support attachments and I luckily found a scrpit mentioned that it does. The script is mentioned [here](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/350)

Now, when I execute, I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'location'
line 75, in with_soap_attachment
```

Can anyone help me why its coming and how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: do you have that script for creating attachments? that link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to replace

```
request = Request(suds_method.client.location(), request_text)
```

with

```
request = Request(soap_method.location(), request_text)
```